# How do I calculate a percentage value from these two time values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two expressions which are calculating across a number of datasets

Expression 1 is as follows:

=Format((count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Authorisation") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPaid") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPended") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "General") * 8 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Reassessment") * 20 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ReserveReview") *3 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Trigger") *5 + Sum(Fields!ACD_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 6 + Sum(Fields!Extn_Out_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 2) / 60, "00") & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", (count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Authorisation") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPaid") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ClaimPended") * 20 + count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "General") * 8 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Reassessment") * 20 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "ReserveReview") *3 +count(Fields!Second_Choice_Options.Value, "Trigger") *5 + Sum(Fields!ACD_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 6 + Sum(Fields!Extn_Out_Calls.Value, "DataSet3") * 2) * 60, "00:00"), "mm:ss")

and the time value is 71:45:00

I then have a second expression which is

=System.Math.Floor(Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value) / 3600) - System.Math.Floor(Sum(Fields!Time_in_Lunch.Value) / 3600)- System.Math.Floor(Sum(Fields!Time_in_AUX_1099.Value) / 3600) & ":" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!Staffed_Time.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")

and the time value is 156:39:22

Therefore I need to make a new calculation in a textbox and take 71:45:00 as a percentage of 156:39:22 and then display that as a percentage - which would be 45.5%

How can I do this?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the two expressions that return a formatted time (i.e.: `70:17:00`) but the expressions that return the number of minutes (i.e.: `4217`), so you can use this formula in a `TextBox` with `Format` property set to `p2`:

```
=[YourExpression1ToObtainMinutes]/[YourExpression2ToObtainMinutes]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tezzo - I've edited the format property to P2 in the textbox but when I divide the two expressions it is showing up as an error

Dan

Comment: Maybe I don't explain this well (sorry for my bad english): you don't have to divide the two expression that returns a formatted datetime but the expression that returns the number of minutes (i.e. not the expression that returns 70:17:00 but the expression that returns 4217).

Comment: yes that makes more sense now, thanks very much. Consider this question answered